# What is the difference between the ports that are shown to be open in these two docker container lists?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, flask, network-programming, devops

I have two separate Ubuntu servers, which I each use to run the same Docker container. The Docker container is run from an image which is a Flask server. For each container I use the same command, docker run --env (environment file) --name (name) -dp 2000:2000 (image registry link). However, one of them is reachable using HTTP, which is the intended result, and the other isn't. Upon running "docker container ls" in each Ubuntu server, I get the following under the "PORTS" column.

For the server that is reachable:

0.0.0.0:2000->2000/tcp

For the server that is not reachable:

0.0.0.0:2000->2000/tcp, :::2000->2000/tcp

What is the difference between these two? Is this maybe the reason the server is not reachable? The port 2000 is open on both machines.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I suspect you are more concerned with the lack of connectivity rather than the difference between the different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

For the server that is reachable:

0.0.0.0:2000->2000/tcp is ipv4

For the server that is not reachable:

0.0.0.0:2000->2000/tcp, :::2000->2000/tcp is ipv4 and ipv6

can you show curl `127.0.0.1:2000` inside the container?